# Is it possible to make a such a call in Skype where there are quite many members (>5 members probably) and only one of them is streaming video?

Tags: audio, video, skype, streaming

Is it possible to make a big party call in Skype, with at least 5 members probably, when only one of them is streaming video while all the others are just streaming audio?

I am just wondering if it is possible to do with Skype what adobe connect does where one is just streaming audio(a teacher or something let's say) and all the others are just watching his video stream(they just don't stream video).

Is that possible? Is that possible with many members in the call?

Comment: A caller can have video with one person they called and voice with another they called. As how to do this, you would do it, doesn’t require you do anything different

Comment: I don't think regular Skype has permission levels similar to Adobe Connect.  What I read is Skype for Business does.  So you could have control over the meeting the same way as Adobe Connect.  You could get an Office 365 business trial and see if it meets your needs.